# Does this proof make sense? $m \mid n$ if and only if $m \mid n^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

Question and proof below. I'm a bit unsure if this proof make sense and want a second opinion. I could find a counter example I guess but I was trying to show that it is the case sometimes but not is not implied for all cases.

Either prove or find a counter-example to the statement $m \:|\: n$ if and only if $m \:|\: n^2$. (Here $n$ and $m$ are integers.)

Proof(Direct)
$m \:|\: n \Leftrightarrow n=km$
$m \:|\: n^2 \Leftrightarrow n^2=lm$
$n^2 = m^2 l^2 = m (m l^2)$
For any Prime $P$ : $P \:|\: ab \Rightarrow (P \:|\: a$ or $P \:|\: b)$
If $m$ is Prime $m \:|\: n^2 \Rightarrow m \:|\: n$
$\therefore \:m \:|\: n \not\Leftrightarrow m \:|\: n^2$ $\blacksquare$

EDIT:

Fixed the double k issue in the original (flawed) proof, alternate proof using counter-example

Proof(Cases)
Suppose $m \mid n$
Then $n = mk$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$
$n^2 = (mk)^2 = m^2 k^2 = m(mk^2)$, so $m \mid n^2$
Suppose $m = 9$ and $n = 6$
Then $9 \mid 6^2 = 36$ but $9 \nmid 6$
$\therefore m \:|\: n \not\Leftrightarrow m \:|\: n^2$ $\blacksquare$

Thanks for the comments and help everyone!

Comment: The statement is clearly false.  $4\,|\,2^2$ but $4\,\nmid \,2$.  The statement of the theorem does not assume that $m$ is prime.  If you want that assumption you have to make it explicit.

Comment: Not wise to use the same letter $k$ for two different cases.

Comment: It certainly is true if $m$ is prime, or more general, if $m$ is “square-free,” which means $m$ is not divisible by any perfect squares $>1.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You reused $k$ in the first and second lines of your proof, though these $k$'s are different (unless $n = 0$).

For the forward direction, suppose $m \mid n$. Then $n = mk$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $n^2 = (mk)^2 = m^2 k^2 = m(mk^2)$, so $m \mid n^2$.

The converse is *not* true in general. Take $m = 9$ and $n = 6$. Then $9 \mid 6^2 = 36$ but $9 \not \mid 6$.

EDIT: I'm going to add a slight addendum, based on an comment that Thomas Andrews made. Specifically, this biconditional holds provided that $m$ is prime.

The forward direction holds by precisely the same argument. Suppose now that $m$ is prime and $m \mid n^2$. Then we have $n^2 = mk$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since $m$ is prime, $m \mid n^2$ immediately requires that $m \mid n$, which is the statement of [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma#:%7E:text=Euclid%27s%20lemma%20%E2%80%94%20If%20a%20prime,143%20must%20be%20as%20well.).